# Using fixtures in Pytest

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, pytest

I have the following code in the conftest.py file

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def app(request):
    global fixture
    browser = request.config.getoption("--browser")
    base_url=target['baseUrl'])
    fixture = Application(browser=browser,base_url=web_config['baseUrl'])
    print("\n BEFORE SESSION")
    fixture.session.login()
    return fixture


@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def stop(request):
    def fin():
        print("\n AFTER SESSION")
        fixture.session.ensure_logout()
        fixture.destroy()
    request.addfinalizer(fin)
    return fixture
```

The test file looks like this. Ie fixture, I obviously do not call.

```
import pytest

@pytest.yield_fixture()
def setup_method():
    print("\n BEFORE METHOD")
    yield
    print("\n AFTER METHOD")

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup_method")
def test_add_text_element(app):
    print("\n RUN TEST")
    app.element.add_blank_page()
    app.element.add_element(element_name='Header')
```

But what if I need to set some other class settings? If I get another fixture, how can I use it in the test file, instead of the one used now?

Answer (score 2):

All about fixtures in py.test you can find in [this](https://docs.pytest.org/en/2.9.1/fixture.html) doc. Below you can found an example how to use fixtures. First of all don't use `global`. Then be careful about `autouse` parameter of fixtures. For setup and teardown `yield_fixture` will be you choice. Use `usefixtures` as decorator for class. Class will be good to organize your test code. You can found more information about usage in this [article](https://habr.com/company/yandex/blog/242795/) (RUS)

`conftest.py`

```py
@pytest.yield_fixture()
def destroy_method():
    yield
    print("\n DESTROY")


@pytest.yield_fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def app(request):
    browser = request.config.getoption("--browser")
    fixture = Application(browser=browser, base_url=web_config['baseUrl'])
    print("\n BEFORE SESSION")
    fixture.session.login()
    yield fixture
    print("\n AFTER SESSION")
    fixture.session.ensure_logout()
    fixture.destroy()
```

Test file will be looks like:

```py
@pytest.yield_fixture()
def setup_method():
    print("\n BEFORE METHOD")
    yield
    print("\n AFTER METHOD")


@pytest.fixture()
def fix1():
    return 1


@pytest.fixture()
def fix2():
    return 2


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup_method", "destroy_method")
class TestSuiteA:
    def test_add_text_element(self, fix1, fix2):
        print("\n RUN TEST")
        assert fix1 + 1 == fix2
```

Answer (score 2):

From pytest docs:

**"yield_fixture" functions:**

> Since pytest-3.0, fixtures using
>   the normal fixture decorator can use a yield statement to provide
>   fixture values and execute teardown code, exactly like yield_fixture
>   in previous versions.
>
> Marking functions as yield_fixture is still supported, but deprecated
>   and should not be used in new code.

Reference: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/yieldfixture.html